# OL3 how as when hovering over a list item, change the style fetures?

Tags: openlayers, jquery

Why not work setStyle to feature?
I try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#tsthov').hover(function(){
    var fetbid = mySource8.getFeatureById("41");

    console.log(fetbid.getStyle());

    var stylecoll = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            //zIndex: -1000,
            anchor: [16, 32],   
            anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            src: 'http://tennisterin.com/images/gmap/maps-point.png'
            //opacity : 0
        }))
    });

    fetbid.setStyle(stylecoll);

},
function(){
  console.log('Out');
});
```

});

But the style does not change.

Initially, I add styles like this:

```
if(clusteredFeatures[0].get('actvstc') == 'active'){
    if(clusteredFeatures[0].get('accode') != ''){
        var linsrc = '/images/clear.png';
    }
    else{
        var linsrc = '/images/pin_blue.png';
    }   
}
else{
    var linsrc = '/images/pin_red.png';
} 
var styleret = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [16, 32],   
        anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: linsrc
    }))
    });

feature.setStyle(styleret);
```

I did based on another 
http://jsfiddle.net/e4reqeqj/37/
It works perfectly

What could be wrong with mine?

**UPD:** It seems I found the reason: For some reason this code is run:

```
    var myLay = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: NEWclusterm,
    style: function(feature, resolution) {
        var 
            clusteredFeatures = feature.get('features'),
            size = feature.get('features').length;
            //console.log(clusteredFeatures[0].get('actvstc'));

        if (size <= 1){ // style for features


            var visi = clusteredFeatures[0].get('visible'),
                inpol = clusteredFeatures[0].get('inpol');
                if(clusteredFeatures[0].get('actvstc') == 'active'){
                    if(clusteredFeatures[0].get('accode') != ''){
                        var linsrc = '/wp-content/themes/morphology-lite/images/clear.png';
                    }
                    else{
                        var linsrc = '/wp-content/themes/morphology-lite/images/pin_blue.png';
                    }


                }
                else{
                    var linsrc = '/wp-content/themes/morphology-lite/images/pin_red.png';
                }

            if(visi == 'visible' || visi == 'fvisible'){
                            var styleret = new ol.style.Style({
                                image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
                                    //zIndex: -1000,
                                    anchor: [16, 32],   
                                    anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                                    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                                    src: linsrc
                                    //opacity : 0
                                }))
                            });
                            feature.setStyle(styleret); 
            }

            if(inpol){
                if(visi == 'visible' && inpol == 'in'){
                    //console.log('in');
                }
                else{
                    var styleret = new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
                            //zIndex: -1000,
                            anchor: [16, 32],   
                            anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                            src: '/wp-content/themes/morphology-lite/images/map_pin_av.png',
                            opacity : 0
                        }))
                    });

                    feature.setStyle(styleret);

                }
            }
        }
        else{ // style for cluster 

            if (size >= 5){
                var clrIS = '#3399CC',//border color
                    clrIF = '#fff',//background color
                    clrTF = '#3399CC',//text color
                    ImgRad = 30,
                    ImgOpct = 0.3,
                    ISWidt = 4;

            }
            else{
                var clrIS = '#3399CC',
                    clrIF = '#fff',
                    clrTF = '#3399CC',
                    ImgRad = 20,
                    ImgOpct = 1,
                    ISWidt = 4; 
            }


            var myStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
                    //zIndex: 9999,
                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
                        radius: ImgRad,
                        opacity: ImgOpct,
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: clrIS,
                            width: ISWidt
                        }),
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: clrIF
                        })
                    }),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        textAlign: "center",
                        textBaseline: "middle",
                        font: '12px sans-serif',
                        text: size.toString(),
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: clrTF
                        })
                    })
                })];


        }
        return myStyle;

    }

});
```

this code inside a "function AddMarkersMin(ifshop, shpnt)"
but "$('#tsthov').hover(function(){" Is outside this function
for whatever reason, he can run?

p\s: sorry for my code, I'm still just learning

Comment: Probably don't create a style every time you hover but should work.  Try calling mySource8.refresh().

Comment: Why don't you revert back to http://tennisterin.com/images/gmap/maps-point.png so we can trust your code a bit more.  Just replace linstr with "http://tennisterin.com/images/gmap/maps-point.png" and maybe post more of your code.

Comment: I changed "tennisterin.com/images/gmap/maps-point.png"; but this did not help, and it's "mySource8.refresh ();" too

Comment: You're going to have to paste your code in its entirety but I'm thinking the style is getting set on hover but the layers getStyle function isn't ever returning that style.  It's also not clear to me where clustering even comes into play.